# Auto populate timestamp in DynamoDB in python using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

Is it possible to have DynamoDB conditionally save a timestamp if the item is created?

It looks like the AWS Java SDK provides this functionality via the [`@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html) annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Your could write/use a DynamoDB trigger - an AWS Lambda function - to do this for you:

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

> ** **Q. How does DynamoDB Triggers work?** **
>   The custom logic for a DynamoDB trigger is stored in an AWS Lambda
>   function as code. To create a trigger for a given table, you can
>   associate an AWS Lambda function to the stream (via DynamoDB Streams)
>   on a DynamoDB table. When the table is updated, the updates are
>   published to DynamoDB Streams. In turn, AWS Lambda reads the updates
>   from the associated stream and executes the code in the function.